# Own Section command working numbered and unnumbered

Tags: macros, sectioning, starred-version

I use the following command to have section headings with subtitles

```
\newcommand{\Section}[2]{\section[#1]{#1\\\small »#2«}}
```

But now I only can have numbered sections because the * doesn't work for my own command. How can I have my command working both ways, with and without the asterisks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the standard way to define *-variants:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xyz}{\@ifstar\@xyzstar\@xyz}
\newcommand{\@xyzstar}<what to do when there's a *>
\newcommand{\@xyz}<what to do when there's not a *>
\makeatother
```

In you case it's probably

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Section}{\@ifstar\@Sectionstar\@Section}
\newcommand{\@Sectionstar}[2]{\section*{#1\\\small »#2«}}
\newcommand{\@Section}[2]{\section[#1]{#1\\\small »#2«}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an intuitive means for incorporating stars `*` in commands. Conditioning on whether you are using a starred/unstarred version is done using `\IfBooleanTF`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\Section}{s m m}{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\section*{#2\\\small \guillemotright #3\guillemotleft}}% Unnumbered section
    {\section[#2]{#2\\\small \guillemotright #3\guillemotleft}}% Numbered section
}
\begin{document}
\Section{First section}{first title}
\Section*{Second section}{second title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should this solution be prefered to the one egreg presented?

Comment: @Sebastian: This might be a user preference. If you're comfortable with @egreg's solution and it is easy for you to modify, then that's that. Otherwise, for me, `xparse` is easy to read in terms of the code, rather than following a sequence of commands. In my answer, `xparse` is an additional package that has to be loaded (that comes with additional functionality). In @egreg's answer, manual definition of 2 commands is required (one for the starred `*` and one for the unstarred version). your choice.

Answer (score 3):

It might be preferable to control section numbering globally. That is, you use non-asterisk sectioning commands everywhere in your document and then you use a command to say which section levels will be numbered.

Here's how to do it. If you place

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
```

in your preamble, then only the highest level section will be numbered.

Comment: I don't want to activate or deactivate it globally but individually with * or without